# Matlab scatter plot of z=f(x,y) with values of z on top of the points

Tags: matlab, plot, scatter

I have a Matlab data set from an equation z=f(x,y).

So for each set of (x,y) I have a corresponding value of z.  Can I plot the data on a x,y plane where at each location **the z-value** is printed instead of a dot or a colored dot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
figure;
hold on;
scatter(x,y);
ma = cellstr(num2str(z(:)));
text(x, y + <some_offset>, ma, 'FontSize', 10, 'Color', 'r');
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

I do not want colors, I have explicitly mentioned that I want numbers (z-vaules) be printed in place of the dots or colors.

Comment: Right, misunderstood the question, As far as I know, you can't create custom markers, so you need to use `text()`

Comment: This text(0.5,0.5,num2str(1.21),'Color','r') is also helpful to reach to the goal.

Comment: Could you please give one +1 to my question if you think it was worth asking, since I am about to get blocked because my questions were poorly received (did not get +1 points)

thanks in advance